# How to run a .bat file from a .exe application in a different folder?

Tags: c#, batch-file, pdflatex

I have an .exe application that opens another .exe application in a different folder, which then executes a .bat file to compile a .tex document.

If the initial .exe application is in a different file to the .tex document it can not find it, but if it is in the same folder it runs perfectly.

Any way I can solve this issue? I need to be able to run the initial .exe from a different folder.

Comment: Can you show us the code how you run the `exe` and `bat` files?

Comment: You should define .exe application path, if you don't define it program runs  from initial folder.

Comment: @Bensinaspa thank you, it worked after defining the path using process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory from below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are calling batch file using Process class, dont forget to set WorkingDirectory property, otherwise it will use your executable` location as default path.

```
var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\Dir\Run.bat";
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"D:\Dir";
process.Start();
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is just what I needed! Sorry for it being trivial!

Comment: Is there a way to pass a command for the .bat file to execute upon being started?

Answer (score 0):

If you use System.Diagnostics.Process.Start you can specify the folder in which to run the batch file.

[System.Diagnosis.Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx)